# Chessboard for beginner

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print Chessboard. Why is this not working?
This code is working for console.log. I want to print it by document.write()
Thanx

```
let size = 8
let result = ''

for(let i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < size ; j++) {

    if(( i + j ) % 2  === 0) {
      result += ' '
    } else {
      result += '#'
    }
  }
  result += '<br>'
} 
document.write(result)

// my output is :
# # # #
# # # #
# # # #
# # # #


//it should like this : 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Comment: Wrap the output in a `pre` tag to preserve whitespace

Comment: wau , it is working ,  Thank you

Comment: Doesn't a chessboard start with a dark square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep constistancy between well indented HTML code and rendered text, browsers *trim* lines, not showing leading and trailing whitespaces.

In example :

```html
<div>
    Hello world
</div>
```

You can notice in the snippet, "Hello world" is indented within the `<div></div>`. When you click *"Run code snippet"*, the rendered HTML is left aligned as if there was no indentation.

If you want to add "visible" spaces, you can use the non-breaking space character code, `&nbsp`

```
let size = 8
let result = ''

for(let i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < size ; j++) {

    if(( i + j ) % 2  === 0) {
      result += '&nbsp;' // <--------------- Check this
    } else {
      result += '#'
    }
  }
  result += '<br>'
} 
document.write(result)
```

Comment: this is working too. thanks